# Android screen shifts down with AdView

Tags: android, adview

How do I prevent my Android screen from shifting down when a page is view is displayed and receives the first add?

When the view is first displayed the screen is normal, then a ad is displayed and the screen shifts down a few lines.

Here is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background3"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxx"
    android:gravity="center"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
</com.google.ads.AdView>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="Start" />

</TableRow>

</LinearLayout>
```

TIA, Trey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have much experience with the ads. But from strictly a View standpoint it seems like what is happening is that the adView is set to View.GONE before it loads. Which means that its space is ignored when placing the other views into the parent.

I don't know for sure how you could get it to not do that. But I would try explicitly setting it to `android:visibility="invisible"` in your xml, then in your java you'll have to make it visible after it has loaded. "invisible" is like gone, but it tells the parent to respect the space that you will take up when you are visible.

Perhaps the loadOnCreate attribute causes the behavior you are seeing? Might also be worth trying it without that and just load it manually in your onCreate.